# List folder names matching specific wild card pattern

Tags: matlab, file, file-manipulation

Matlab script shown below, lists all folders inside current directory. How can I list all folders which match specific wildcard pattern such as `*pattern*` or `Sample*`?

```
files = dir(pwd)
% Get a logical vector that tells which is a directory.
dirFlags = [files.isdir]
% Extract only those that are directories.
subFolders = files(dirFlags)
% Print folder names to command window.
for k = 1 : length(subFolders)
    fprintf('Sub folder #%d = %s\n', k, subFolders(k).name);
end
```

Comment: `dir([pwd '\*pattern*'])`

Comment: @Adiel It will list all files including directories. I want only directories to be listed

Comment: So you use `isdir` in the next step. Or you can do  `dir([pwd '\*pattern*\ *'])` . (Without the space, that's just for displaying here)